# Back button manipulation

Tags: javascript, html, css

This is actually a continuation of the [Creating a selected tab in a HTML tabstrip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70724038/creating-a-selected-tab-in-a-html-tabstrip) question. Since that question is basically answered I decided it would be best to ask this as a new question rather than add to the previous thread.

[Here is my page](https://wayneca.neocities.org/FFXII/items1.html) so you can see what I mean. Try to use the back button after clicking on one or more tabs.

I have researched controlling the back button and have found that it seems to only deal with the issue of clicking the button resulting in being taken to a different page than you are expecting. This is not the issue I am having. For me it's about what the tabstrip shows.

Using the page I have linked to, suppose that I click each tab in order from first to last. I have now created 16 different tab selections. Clicking the browser's back button will take you back page-by-page, but the tab selected will remain the same. But what if I was just jumping from one tab to another and in short order I have looked at 8 of those pages but have clicked tabs 25 times?

Trying to remember all of the tabs clicked no matter how many times or in what order is, in my opinion, too much. Perhaps it would be better to just have the tabs reset to none selected if you click the back button.

I am wondering, is tracking all of the tab changes not as preposterous as I think it is? Or is it better to just reset the tabstrip to none selected if the back button is clicked?

And, of course, how would I go about implementing this, regardless of which way it's done?

Comment: Questions need to stand on their own. You need to bring the relevant code here. These aren't discussion threads, but Q&A pairs. Also, you seem to be asking for opinions. That would be off topic.

Comment: I can put the code here. I didn't think it was necessary given that it exists on the previous thread. I am asking for opinions as I don't know enough about javascript or browser programming to provide any examples of what I am trying to do, and I am not sure what the best approach would be.